# Refresh form if a checkbox is checked

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I'm hoping someone can help me here. I tried asking before but no one seemed to get what I wanted so going to rephrase it and try again.

I have a very simple form it has a drop down of a list of names, a check box, and a submit button.

The list of names is pulled from my database. The checkbox is initially unchecked. What I want to happen is when I check the checkbox the list of names is updated to include additional names.

What I have tried:

```
    1. <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="Yes" onclick="$('#myform').submit()">
    2. <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="Yes" onclick="this.form.submit()">
    3. <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" onclick="$('#myform').submit()">
    4. <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="Yes" onclick="$('#myform').submit();">
    5. <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="Yes" onclick="this.form.submit();">
    6. <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1" onclick="$('#myform').submit();">
```

none of these will refresh the form. I don't know if this changes anything but my submit button has an id of submit. I'm not great with jQuery or javascript at this time so I'm not sure what to do to get this to function the way I want. I am using php as the base coding for the page, with mysql for the query. I have the conditional statement in the sql query as such:

```
    if ($_POST['active'] == 'Yes') {
      echo "query holds all";   
    } else {    
      echo "query holds some";
    }
```

this messages appear correctly if I manually change the output, but when I check the box it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there another way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the inline onclick events on checkbox

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="active"]', function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $('#myform').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok I tried this and even added an alert to see if it got here, unfortunately it doesn't change the sql statement in my php. The alert pops up but the second message I have doesn't show. It still shows "query holds some".

Comment: As an additional note I pulled everything out of the page to see if there was something messing with it, but nothing seems to be affecting it. When I check the box it still does nothing to the form. I can't refresh the page because that will uncheck the box is there another way to do this? maybe another drop down or a radio button?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" id="chk" value="Yes" onclick="return check()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function check()

{
    //alert(document.getElementById("chk").checked);
    if(document.getElementById("chk").checked == true)
    {
        window.location.reload();
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I was reading on this, but won't that reload the whole page, causing the checkbox to become unchecked again? I will try this anyway when I get home and let you know.

Comment: k sure.. when you click checkbox at that time page was reload and when you unchecked then page was not reload.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" value="Yes" 
onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

The only problem you will have is that, by reloading the page, the check will disappear.

What you need to do is give the "Checked" and create a variable value and put it into the operation, something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" id="active" value="checked" 
<?php echo  $active_flag;?> onchange="this.form.submit();" />
```

where

```
$active_flag= $_POST['active_flag'];
```